# How can I disable "demand paging" for one of my userspace programs?

Tags: linux, linker, linux-kernel, glibc

For an dedicated test I have to disable "demand paging"
for exactly one of my userspace programs

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging
```

Any idea how I could do this ?
(embedded linux appliance; 2.6 kernel)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to modify the application, you could use the `mlock()` / `mlockall()` system calls to ensure that your memory doesn't get paged out:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

mlockall(MCL_FUTURE);
```

This will prevent all memory currently allocated, and any future memory that is allocated to this process from being swapped out.  You can use the `mlock()` system call to get finer control over which parts of memory are locked.

Comment: I have a problem with initialisation (C++, do_global_ctors_aux)
 to debug this I want to make sure that from the very beginning everything is 
  - and remains in memory
- so maybe mlockall is too late for this

Comment: In that case, you can disable your swap device altogether :)

I'm not aware of a way to do the equivalent of mlockall to another process.  You could try and hack the executable to insert a call to mlockall as the very first thing to do when the application starts.

Comment: Demand paging is not related to swapping out unused pages, but it is the lazy loading of the executable from disk. The combination of mlockall(MCL_CURRENT) and mklockall(MCL_FUTURE) should effectively disable demand paging.